Ubuntu became very slow out of nowhere and a lot of apps do not open anymore, including the terminal
The last thing I did on the pc was reinstalling Orchis theme following the steps from the github page and using the stylepak script for both user and system. Then I tried changing my qt cursor config so it would match the gtk one. I did that using sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme and as soon as I reboot the pc to test if it worked, the pc went into this strange state.
Fans maxed out, terminal doesn't open. DING extension appeared to be disabled and when I tried to re-enable it the extension manager didn't list any extensions, be it system or user-installed.

Recommend a reinstall of the Ubuntu OS. Seems you may have hosed the OS.
